# Multiselect listbox item returning system.windows.controls.listboxitem: with the listboxitem value

Tags: c#, listbox, listboxitem

Listboxitems that are selected return **system.windows.controls.listboxitem: ExampleValue.**

```
private void Trade_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
   {
        TradesSelected.Text = "";
        foreach (object trade in Trade.SelectedItems)
      {
        TradesSelected.Text += (TradesSelected.Text == "" ? "" : ",") + trade.ToString();
      }
    }
```

How can you remove the **system.windows.controls.listboxitem:** part so it will just show **ExampleValue**?

```
<StackPanel>
                    <TextBox x:Name="TradesSelected" Width="300" Padding="2" ></TextBox>
                    <ListBox SelectionMode="Multiple" x:Name="Trade" Width="300" Height="100" Padding="2" SelectionChanged="Trade_SelectionChanged">
                        <ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
                            <Style TargetType="ListBoxItem">
                                <Setter Property="IsSelected" Value="{Binding IsSelected}"/>
                            </Style>
                        </ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
                        <ListBoxItem>ExampleOne</ListBoxItem>
                        <ListBoxItem>ExampleTwo</ListBoxItem>
                        <ListBoxItem>ExampleThree</ListBoxItem>
                    </ListBox>
                </StackPanel>
```

Comment: How do you set the Items collection of the ListBox? Do you add items one by one or do you set the DataSource for the ListBox? Seeing this code is important to give a precise answer

Comment: @Steve see edit

Comment: see my answer with regards to your edit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to cast your `trade` object to the type it actually is. The `.ToString()` method of the `object` type simply returns the type name. See [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.object.tostring?view=netframework-4.7.2#Overriding).

Also, probably the type that the trade object really is, has a property/field/method that returns the string value that you actually want to show.

```
TradesSelected.Text += (TradesSelected.Text == "" ? "" : ",") + (trade as ListBoxItem).Content.ToString();
```

Comment: Perfect! Thank you !